# looking for marker text option for pyplot.plot()

Tags: python, text, matplotlib, plot, markers

I am looking for a way to insert numbers or text into markers. There  is nothing in the `matplotlib.pyplot.plot(*args, **kwargs)` documentation about that.

The default zoom level places markers on the edge, hence reducing the available space on which to inscribe text.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [1, 2, 3, 4 ,5]
y = [1, 4, 9, 6, 10]
plt.plot(x, y, 'ro',markersize=23)
plt.show()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not practical because of a larger plot and the zoom-in feature"?

Comment: Do you know about [Annotations in MatPlotLib](http://matplotlib.org/users/annotations_intro.html)?

Answer (score 9):

As jkalden suggested, `annotate` would solve your problem. The function's `xy`-argument let you position the text so that you can place it on the marker's position.

About your "zoom" problem, `matplotlib` will by default stretch the frame between the smallest and largest values you are plotting. It results in your outer markers having their centers on the very edge of the figure, and only half of the markers are visible. To override the default x- and y-limits you can use `set_xlim` and `set_ylim`. Here an offset is define to let you control the marginal space.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1, 2, 3, 4 ,5]
y = [1, 4, 9, 6, 10]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# instanciate a figure and ax object
# annotate is a method that belongs to axes
ax.plot(x, y, 'ro',markersize=23)

## controls the extent of the plot.
offset = 1.0 
ax.set_xlim(min(x)-offset, max(x)+ offset)
ax.set_ylim(min(y)-offset, max(y)+ offset)

# loop through each x,y pair
for i,j in zip(x,y):
    corr = -0.05 # adds a little correction to put annotation in marker's centrum
    ax.annotate(str(j),  xy=(i + corr, j + corr))

plt.show()
```

Here is how it looks:

[image: Running the suggested code above gives a figure like this.]

Answer (score 4):

This is a revision of @snake_charmer 's method.  I used alignment options (instead of manual offsets) to center the text on the dot, and other options for color, size and boldness (weight) of the text.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1, 2, 3, 4 ,5]
y = [1, 4, 9, 6, 10]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# instantiate a figure and ax object
# annotate is a method that belongs to axes
ax.plot(x, y, 'ro',markersize=23)

## controls the extent of the plot.
offset = 1.0 
ax.set_xlim(min(x)-offset, max(x)+ offset)
ax.set_ylim(min(y)-offset, max(y)+ offset)

# loop through each x,y pair
for i,j in zip(x,y):
    ax.annotate(str(j),  xy=(i, j), color='white',
                fontsize="large", weight='heavy',
                horizontalalignment='center',
                verticalalignment='center')

plt.show()
```

[image: numbers on top of dots]

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using MathText.
Here are the instructions from [matplotlib.org](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/marker_reference.html)

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.4)

marker_style.update(mec="None", markersize=15)
markers = ["$1$", r"$\frac{1}{2}$", "$f$", "$\u266B$", r"$\mathcal{A}$"]


for y, marker in enumerate(markers):
    # Escape dollars so that the text is written "as is", not as mathtext.
    ax.text(-0.5, y, repr(marker).replace("$", r"\$"), **text_style)
    ax.plot(y * points, marker=marker, **marker_style)
format_axes(ax)
fig.suptitle('mathtext markers', fontsize=14)

plt.show()
```

Comment: The original question is about adding text to *existing* markers, which in the asker's example were dots.  You answered with markers that were simply text.  Is there a way to combine two marker types into one?  Or maybe a text option on dot markers?