# matplotlib changing marker font throws ValueError?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I want to change the font of a marker to roman ( ideally gill sans). the docs tell me that this is a valid code statement BUT it's throwing

```
ValueError: 
 \mathrmAAPL 
 ^
Unknown symbol: \mathrmAAPL (at char 1), (line:1, col:2)
```

I can't use plot.text so I really would like to get this working as is. If you UNCOMMENT the line that works you will see what the code does. Basically data points with markers replaced by TEXT. It's exactly what I want BUT I need to change the font.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = []
y = []

symbol = "AAPL"

x = range(5)
y = [5,10,12,15,11]

# this line plots BUT font is italic so I need to change it
# plt.plot(x,y,lw=2.5,color='r',linestyle='solid',marker=r"$ {} $".format(symbol),markersize=25)

#THIS line throws the error

plt.plot(x,y,lw=2.5,color='r',linestyle='solid',marker=r"$ \mathrm{} $".format(symbol),markersize=25)

plt.show()
```

ValueError: 
\mathcalAAPL 
^
Unknown symbol: \mathcalAAPL (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if I do:

```
plt.plot(x,y,lw=2.5,color='r',linestyle='solid',marker=r"$\mathrm{%s}$" % symbol, markersize=25)
```

it works fine.

Obviously, your `format` worked wrong, you could have checked it by hardcoding the symbol.
As pionted out in the comment, `marker=r"$ \mathrm {{{}}} $".format(symbol)` would have been correct. (You had no space after the mathrm, so this gave an error, but it didn't work even with the space; and you had no braces around the symbol, so only the first letter would have been roman, if it had worked).

Thank you for the hint, I didn't know this feature with text as marker!

Comment: Syntax with `.format` should be: `marker=r"$ \mathrm {{{}}} $".format(symbol)`

Comment: yes, it works, I checked it and edited the answer; thank you :)

Comment: @Vadim Shkaberda  and Ilja WOW thanks both. I do have a question though for Vadim, I am new to Python and wonder HOW you figured the formatting out? I ask because I would like to have Gill Sans font instead of timeroman. I am having trouble working out how you got to that statement which works PERFECTLY thank you so much both

Comment: maybe Vadim can help you, but it would be a coincidence - he proposed pure-python formatting of a string, this is not connected to such internals of matplotlib. There are probably only few fonts installed, and probably you cannot run arbitrary tex commands? It could take a lot of research in the reference to be sure :)

Comment: Ok thanks IIja really helped me out. I am happy we both learnt something.

Comment: @theakson If you want to select another font in context of math expression you should change `\mathrm` (e.g., `\mathsf` uses SansSerif). Available fonts you can find [here](http://matplotlib.org/users/mathtext.html). If you want to customize fonts in math expression you should [customize matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html#customizing-matplotlib). Another approach to add text as markers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27577668/looking-for-marker-text-option-for-pyplot-plot.

Comment: hey @VadimShkaberda thanks for the follow up BUT I already am onto the \mathsf etc AND using text as markers really would be my last resort. Could you tell me where to look to understand the brackets in your answer please I don't really get it marker=r"$ \mathrm {{{}}} $".format(symbol)  it's the {{{}}} bit I don't know where to start. Sorry to be so dense but I am still learning python.

Comment: @ theakson At first, there should be two pair of  `{}`, cause first pair required as math. expr. `\mathrm {...}` and second as a “replacement field” for `format`. With two pair of brackets I got `RuntimeError: In affine_transform: Invalid vertices array.`, so I understood second pair of brackets is also processed as a part of math. expr.. So I just added another pair of brackets as the “replacement field”.

Comment: @theakon You can also play with interpreter and see what `marker` gets with various pair of brackets:  1.`r"$\mathrm{key}$".format(key=symbol)` gives `'$\\mathrmA$'` which is obviously an error.  2.`r"$\mathrm{{key}}$".format(key=symbol)` gives `'$\\mathrm{key}$'`  3.`r"$\mathrm{{{key}}}$".format(key=symbol)` gives `'$\\mathrm{AAPL}$'`.

Comment: WOW @VadimShkaberda thanks so much for taking the time. I had completely forgotten about the interpreter !  I should have remembered this approach. Again thanks for all your EXCELLENT help to a struggling noob trying to get to grips with Python.